# delayed_job - environment loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

A quite simple question I can't find a definite answer for.

Does the delayed_job process load the rails environment and keep it open?
I need to keep the state of a variable (for emailing purposes).

Currently I use `ar_sendmail` but its daemon reloads the environment each time (every 5mins), and I lose the state of a variable.

Comment: Could you share what sort of state you're storing in that variable? Keeping state that way isn't advisable - even if your solution doesn't reload the Rails env each time, there's no way you can guarantee it'll never crash - and thus lose the state. You're better off keeping it elsewhere. In the database perhaps?

Comment: I'm doing a hack to get around Gmail's per account limit. `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings[:user_name] = "account#{ActionMailer::ARSendmail.my_count}@domain.com"` (simple version). my_count is the variable which I'd like in state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used delayed jobs extensively in rails and in my personal experience, please persist the variable you are talking about in a database and de-couple yourself from maintaing the state of a variable in the rails process.